# Setting up a proxy with a whitelisted ip with Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I fully understand the code below except one line.
I subscribed to a proxy provider (Proxymesh) and whitelisted my ip from there.

My question seems quite simple but I can't figure out how to solve it: how can I get a working ip to use as PROXY variable (here 23.23... as an exemple) ? I keep getting a blank Chrome window with a proxy error...

Many thanks

```py
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "23.23.23.23:3128" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Comment: I think your proxy isn't working. Try to replace another proxy

Comment: Yes it is. The 23.23.23.23:3180 ip is just an exemple and curling ip info shows that it changes. I'm looking for a way to get this rotating ip in Python to set the PROXY variable.